# Having trouble changing int variable value (Tic Tac Toe)

Tags: c#, methods, tic-tac-toe

Here is the playerTurn Method.

```
public static void playerTurn(int player) 
{
    if (player == 1)
    {
        player = 2;
   }
    else if(player == 2) { player = 1; }
}
```

Why won't the player change when the playerTurn Method is called. I tried changing the initial value of player 1 and messing around with the if else statement but it didn't work. I'm still a newbie to C# so I could be doing something wrong elsewhere but I'm not sure what else to try.

```
static void Main(string[] args) //MAIN METHOD
{
    int player = 1;
    int inputNum;

    int turns = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("Player1: X");
    Console.WriteLine("Player2: O");
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
    SetField();

    openMessage(player);

    string input = Console.ReadLine();


    if (int.TryParse(input, out inputNum))
    {
        inputNum = int.Parse(input);
        turns++;
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid input!");
    }

    switch (player) 
    {
        case 1:switch (inputNum) 
            { 
                case 1: playField[0, 0] = playerSign(player); break;
                case 2: playField[0, 1] = playerSign(player); break;
                case 3: playField[0, 2] = playerSign(player); break;
                case 4: playField[1, 0] = playerSign(player); break;
                case 5: playField[1, 1] = playerSign(player); break;
                case 6: playField[1, 2] = playerSign(player); break;
                case 7: playField[2, 0] = playerSign(player); break;
                case 8: playField[2, 1] = playerSign(player); break;
                case 9: playField[2, 2] = playerSign(player); break;
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            switch (inputNum)
            {
                case 1: playField[0, 0] = playerSign(player); break;
                case 2: playField[0, 1] = playerSign(player); break;
                case 3: playField[0, 2] = playerSign(player); break;
                case 4: playField[1, 0] = playerSign(player); break;
                case 5: playField[1, 1] = playerSign(player); break;
                case 6: playField[1, 2] = playerSign(player); break;
                case 7: playField[2, 0] = playerSign(player); break;
                case 8: playField[2, 1] = playerSign(player); break;
                case 9: playField[2, 2] = playerSign(player); break;
            }
            break;
    }

    SetField();

    Console.WriteLine(player);
    playerTurn(player);

    //player 1 turn end
    Console.WriteLine(player);
    openMessage(player);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: You're passing a copy of `player` to `playerTurn`, so you're modifying the copy.

Comment: You should read up on the difference between _Value Types_ and _Reference Types_.  Ignore anything that might be there about "oh, value types are on the stack", concentrate on how assignments differ between the two groupings of types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter is passed by value to this method. Therefore it only gets a copy of the value. Return the new value. Also, you can simplify the playerTurn method:

```cs
public static int playerTurn(int player)
{
    return 3 - player; // Switches player from 1 to 2 or vice-versa.
}
```

`3 - 2 = 1`. `3 - 1 = 2`.
Call it with

```cs
player = playerTurn(player);
```

---

You can get the indexes in a simpler way with some math:

```cs
playField[(inputNum - 1) / 3, (inputNum - 1) % 3] = playerSign(player);
```

`/` performs an integer division, truncating the result to the next lower integer number. `%` yields the remainder of this division.

And there is no point in switching on the `player`, since both cases are identical. This allows you to replace 31 lines of code by just one.

---

Note also that your game doesn't have a loop. Therefore, it will stop after the 1st player has made its move.

Comment: When you write code like `return 3 - player;`, it's an excellent place to put a comment like `//switches player from 1 to 2 or vice-versa`.  A year from now when you look at the code, it will likely be a head-scratcher without the comment

Comment: @Flydog57: Excellent suggestion! Done.

Answer (score 1):

This method:

```
public static void playerTurn(int player) 
    {
        if (player == 1)
        {
            player = 2;
        }
        else if(player == 2) { player = 1; }
    }
```

Takes a copy of whatever is passed in and modifies the copy. What you need to do is pass the value in by reference:

```
public static void playerTurn(ref int player)
    ...
```

This way whatever variable is passed in to the playerTurn method gets modified directly.